# How to best cover corrugated plastic along basement wall without affecting the catching of wall water?

Tags: basement, tile, drain, plastic

We recently had the drain tile replaced in our basement. We are in the process of putting in vinyl planks in the unfinished portion, and have these black plastic correlated pieces lining the walls.

Per the basement company who did the repair, we can't tamper with the plastic otherwise it would void the warranty. Can this be covered or hidden and still serve its purpose of catching water?!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ask the company that did the work if your plans would void the warranty. Regardless of anything any of us could say on here, it comes down to the company honoring the warranty.